# Rails 5 Simpleform not updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, nested-forms

Sorry I've looked at similar questions to this but still can't figure it out for some reason...

I'm using Devise and I'm trying to update my User model and a City model at the same time (through the edit registrations page) using a nested form.

I'm updating the users city based on a set of predefined values that are in the database. So all the user has to do is select a city they are living in from a list and then it save.

All that happens at the moment is the form submits but the city isn't changed.

Thanks in advance!

```
#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
end

#city.rb
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

My Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(city_attributes: [:id, :name, :user_id])
  end
end
```

And my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

      <%= f.simple_fields_for :city do |c| %>

      <%= c.input :city_id, collection: City.all.order(name: :asc), label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: "City", include_blank: false, selected: @user.city_id %>

      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't work because the form doesn't post back to your users_controller. You have to override the `routes.rb` file in a specific way to tell Devise to use your controller.

Comment: Thanks @Iceman. I posted my answer below now and my issue is sorted. Nested attributes still don't work though but that's something I'll come back to another time.

Comment: Glad you got it working, maybe I'll look into the other problem sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I sorted my problem out based on the comment from Iceman and response from ajerferson.

**(However the issue that the nested form doesnt work still remains, but my issue is fixed)**

As Iceman said Devise was permitting its own parameters in my application controller. So I moved the parameters there (instead of changing my routes).

```
# application_controller.rb
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :gender, city_attributes: [:id, :name, :user_id]])
  end
```

I tried again but the same problems were occuring. So what I did was actually scrap the nested form and simply change my application controller to this and targetting the city_id foreign key:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :gender, :city_id])
  end
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :city_id, collection: City.all.order(name: :asc), label: "City" %>

<%= f.button :submit, "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

and now it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:city_id)
end
```